# Apk is not building properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I have created an android app. in my app, it is connected with firebase. So, when someone inputs any data like name, mobile number, blood group, FB id they store in the real-time database. and when people search with blood group it shows name, mobile number, and FB id. also, I have added a map, when people click to show map it shows location on the map. However, when I deploy my project through the android studio to my devices, it works fine. no problem displays. But when I sign it and generate a signed apk which is release type, I install it into my device manually then two function goes away.

First one: It doesn't display facebook id. It shows null, also if someone inputs facebook id then in the database it stores nothing. Even if I input fb child manually in the database it shows me a null message.

2nd problem: Map doesn't store location properly and doesn't display any maps.

What could be the problem?

here's my activity for datasubmission:

```
    public class DonorForm extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner batchChoice;
    Spinner groupChoice;

    EditText Name;
    EditText Mobile;
    EditText Fb;

    Button Save;

    ProgressBar progressBar;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_donor_form);

        batchChoice = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdownBatch);

        String[] batchs = new String[]{"N-15","N-16", "N-17", "N-18","N-19", "N-20", "N-21", "N-22","N-23","N-24","N-25", "N-26","N-27", "N-28", "N-29", "N-30","N-31","N-32", "N-33", "N-34","N-35", "N-36", "N-37", "N-38","N-39", "N-40","N-41","N-42","N-43", "N-44","N-45", "N-46", "N-47", "N-48","N-49","N-50", "N-51", "N-52","N-53", "N-54", "N-55", "N-56","N-57", "N-58", "N-59", "N-60","BDS-1", "BDS-2","BDS-3", "BDS-4", "BDS-5", "BDS-6","BDS-7", "BDS-8", "BDS-9", "BDS-10","BDS-11", "BDS-12","BDS-13", "BDS-14", "BDS-15", "BDS-16","BDS-17", "BDS-18", "BDS-19", "BDS-20"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, batchs);
        batchChoice.setAdapter(adapter);


        groupChoice = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dropdownGroup);
        String[] group = new String[]{"O+","O-", "A+", "B+","A-", "B-", "AB+", "AB-"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, group);
        groupChoice.setAdapter(adapter1);

        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_mobileNumber);
        Fb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_fb);

        Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_saveDonor);

        Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = Name.getText().toString();
                String batch = batchChoice.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String group = groupChoice.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String mobile = Mobile.getText().toString();
                String lat = MainActivity.lat.toString();
                String lng = MainActivity.lng.toString();
                String fb = Fb.getText().toString();


                if(fb.length()>20 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(DonorForm.this, "Please Enter valid facebook username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{ if(name.length()>25 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(DonorForm.this, "Please Enter less than 25 character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {if(mobile.length()<11 ||mobile.length()>11 )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(DonorForm.this, "Please Enter 11 Digit Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Donor donor = new Donor(name,mobile,group,batch,lat, lng,fb);
                    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("donors");
                    myRef.child(batch).child(group).push().setValue(donor);

                    finish();
                }}


                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

here's my activity for data view from firebase:
 Button buttonMap;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_donor_list);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    city = extras.getString("city");
    group = extras.getString("group");
    Log.i("NAME",city);
    Log.i("NAME",group);

    donorList = new ArrayList<>();
    donorInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_donor);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.list, donorList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    buttonMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_mapShow);
    buttonMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(DonorList.this, MapsActivity.class));
        }
    });



    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("donors");

    myRef.child(city).child(group).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Donor donor = dataSnapshot.getValue(Donor.class);
            donorInfo.add(donor);
            String donorInfo = "Name : "+ donor.name + "   \nNumber : " + donor.contuctNumber + "   \nFb Username: " + donor.fb;
            donorList.add(donorInfo);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

here's the map adctivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng you = new LatLng(MainActivity.lat, MainActivity.lng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(you).title("Your Position").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(you , 15.0f) );


        for(int i=0; i<DonorList.donorInfo.size(); i++){
            Log.d("Donor", String.valueOf(i));


            Donor donor = DonorList.donorInfo.get(i);
            Double lat = new Double(donor.lat);
            Double lng = new Double(donor.lan);

            Log.d("Donor", donor.lat);
            Log.d("Donor", donor.lan);


            LatLng donar = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            String donorName = donor.name+ " " + donor.contuctNumber;
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(donar).title(donorName));
        }
    }
}
```

here's the gradle.build module file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nissan.dnmcbloodbank"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have you tested database access from the phone without using your app? Your database settings do not need to be show here in regards to the private parts. But you may want to put information on or explain the configuration in some form as well to help people answer the question. It sounds like a database access issue. Is it centrally hosted or locally on phone? Is the database being persisted on disk or in memory? Does each app installed per phone just access a shared database or makes its own?

Comment: my database is in firebase realtime database. I tested.all ok. But after building it as a generated apk fb part don't work

Comment: Yes I get that its not working. I do not know how firebase database you speak of works. Not everyone uses the same technologies. I use MongoDB, H2, MySQL and SQLite that I self host. For one my clients never have access to the databases and the server does all of the proxying of the data. So I was asking you the above questions to be answered so anyone can help who does not know firebase or how its databases work in relation to mobile apps. Edit: Added for others: https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/  Your question feels vague with the information you provided.